# RS232 chat. Simplest way?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, serial-port

I'm working in a project in which I will have to deal with serial communications. For testing, I want make to 2 computers speak to each other (with my interaction) via RS232.

Will the next thing work?

in computer A:

```
# cat /dev/ttyS0
```

in computer B:

```
# echo <something> >> /dev/ttyS0
```

Will computer A, receive data from B, or not?

If I'm wrong, what would be the easiest way to send something to the other computer?

Ideas are welcome!

Comment: This is probably a question better asked at stack overflow

Comment: @falmarri: this isn't a programming question, so why?

Comment: @falmarri: Toadette is right, and my question is related only to unix enviroments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to communicate via the serial port you have to setup the right parameters (baud, stop bit, parity,handshake etc.).

I used [minicom](http://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom) in the past for stuff like using a computer as a serial console terminal to another.

The [cu command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cu) is an alternative.

Comment: I tried that way yesterday, but it didn't work... Could it be the cable? Don't know if it had crossed TX and RX, because I borrowed it.

Comment: Well, I am no fortune teller ... Sure, the cable could always be the problem. But serial cables are easy to check via a continuity tester (usually available in every voltmeter). Just buy a new cable, they are really cheap ...

Answer (score 4):

An easier way, if you know how to program in python, might be for you to use an API available for python called **PYSERIAL** so that you don't have to worry about doing any of the dirty work of setting up flags or passing parameters to the driver that handles the serial port on your computer. Pyserial takes care of all this for you in the background.

You would have to specify the baud rate at most, and leave the rest as default for a working serial connection between the 2 computers.

The entire code for enabling such a connection could be at the most a few lines or half a page long.

Comment: This is why I suggested this might be better on stackoverflow =P